# how to get data from rows where date(format monyy) is greater than today

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database with a column listing the dates as MONYY ex. FEB05,JUN12, etc. I want to get data from rows with date>= today. I tried using to_date as below

```
select t.date, t.data, to_date(t.date, 'monyy') from table t
   where to_date(t.date,'monyy') >='8/1/2012'
```

But I get error saying that FROM keyword is not at expected location.

Need help in writing this query.

Comment: Please include the ***exact*** query you ran *(you have a comment saying this is just an example, and that the name `table` is different in your query)* and the ***exact*** error message you received. Para-phrasing things in this way has removed information that we need to help you.

Comment: Is the column really named `date`?

Comment: Also, you should `to_date` _everything_ that is not already a date. Don't assume that Oracle will transform _any_ string into a date, let alone do it correctly. As a more general rule always store dates as dates not strings.

Answer (score 0):

`table` is a reserved word and not a valid table name. Exchange `table` for the actual name of your table.

**Edit:**
I tried it, and it worked if I changed the final date to:

```
to_date('8/1/2012', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: It was an example, I'm using the correct table name 'SalesData'

Comment: If your actual table name is TABLE then enclose it in double-quotes.  However, using reserved words for the names of objects in the database is bad practice - if you can, change the name to something meaningful.